# MKDIR command saying file doesn't exist, even though it does

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cp, mkdir

When I try to make a directory or copy a file onto my Windows 10 partition, I get this error:

```
mkdir /mnt/Windows/Test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Test’: No such file or directory
```

Even though the directory exists, as evidenced by running this command:

```
/mnt/Windows
bash: /mnt/Windows: Is a directory
```

I've tried:

Running mkdir as sudo

Making sure the partition wasn't read-only

CD'ing into the partition before making the folder

Using the -P argument for mkdir

Googling and searching StackOverflow

None of these worked.

Comment: It's likely to be permissions.Windows doesn't like you to write stuff in the Windows directory

Comment: How would i change the permissions? I've already tried chmod +755, didn't work.